# Saved to Server, Want it to Update JSON File

Tags: javascript, json, post, backbone.js, mamp

Using BackgridJS.com for this project, and I want to be able to update text in a cell, and have it automatically update the corresponding JSON file. (The cell's original text is pulled from a JSON file"

From the BackgridJS website:

> How do I save my row changes to the server immediately?

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      initialize: function () {
    Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.on("change", function (model, options) {
      if (options && options.save === false) return;
      model.save();
    });
  }
});
```

This works on my site, because when I update the cell, it POSTs successfully. It posts like this:

```
city: "Example"
country: "Example"
type: "Example"
url: "http://example.com"
year: "Example"
```

I am using MAMP. How would I be able to update the JSON file when I update the cell?

Comment: Anyone know anyway to do this? If I need to use another language too, then that's fine. Just want to know the easiest way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [POST Working, But Not Updating File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435358/post-working-but-not-updating-file)